# How to replace first two matching patterns with the condition in R

Tags: r, string, pattern-matching

I have this vector called `myvec`. I want to replace the first two dots (if present before `_`) in each element with "`-`". How can I do this in R and get the result?

```
myvec <- c("SKDP.209.3_C4UAMACXX.7.04.ReCal.sort.bam", "SKDP.97.1_C4UAMACXX.7.12.ReCal.sort.bam", 
    "SKDP972_C4UAMACXX.7.13.ReCal.sort.bam")
```

result

```
SKDP-209-3_C4UAMACXX.7.04.ReCal.sort.bam, SKDP-97-1_C4UAMACXX.7.12.ReCal.sort.bam, 
    SKDP972_C4UAMACXX.7.13.ReCal.sort.bam
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can try with `gsub`.  Using the capture groups i.e characters placed within `(...)`, check for one more characters that are not a `.` (`([^.]+)`), followed by a dot (`\\.` as `.` is a metacharacter which can match for any character, we need to escape it) followed by another set of capture groups that are not a dot followed by dot and then the third capture group, which include one or more characters that are not a `_` followed by a `_` (`([^_]+_`)and the rest of the characters until the end of the string (`.*`)  and replace by the backreference for the capture groups i.e. `\\1` for the first one, followed by `-` then the second backreference...

```
gsub("^([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)\\.([^_]+_.*)", "\\1-\\2-\\3", myvec)
#[1] "SKDP-209-3_C4UAMACXX.7.04.ReCal.sort.bam"
#[2] "SKDP-97-1_C4UAMACXX.7.12.ReCal.sort.bam"
#[3] "SKDP972_C4UAMACXX.7.13.ReCal.sort.bam"
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain a bit on this part `\\1-\\2-\\3"`?

Comment: @MAPK Sure, just a min